# How do I ensure there are no conflicting Chrome processes running before running my Selenium script?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown 
error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location
 C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running,
 so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

chrome_options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 1')
chrome_options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\ADMIIN\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data')
```

I'm trying to scrap a website using a specific chrome profile i.e.. Profile 1